# Append new column by subtracting existing column in csv by using python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I tried to append new column to an existing csv file using python. it is not showing any error but the column is not created.

I have a CSV  file with 5 columns and I want to add data in the 6th column by subtracting between existing columns.

ID,SURFACES,A1X,A1Y,A1Z,A2X

1,GROUND,800085.3323,961271.977,-3.07E-18,800080.8795

ADD THE COLUMN AX( = A1X - A2X)

CODE:

```
>>> x = csv.reader(open('E:/solarpotential analysis/iitborientation/trialcsv.csv','rb'))
>>> y = csv.writer(open('E:/solarpotential analysis/iitborientation/trial.csv','wb',buffering=0))

>>> for row in x:
        a = float(row[0])
        b = str(row[1])
        c = float(row[2])
        d = float(row[3])
        e = float(row[4])
        f = float(row[2] - row[5])
    y.writerow([a,b,c,d,e,f])
```

it shows no error but not be updated in output file

Comment: Can you add the code, some sample input and some sample output please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by this way:

```
inputt=open("input.csv","r")
outputt=open("output.csv","w")
for line in inputt.readlines():
    #print line.replace("\n","")
    outputt.write(line.replace("\n","") + ";6column\n")

inputt.close()
outputt.close()
```

Comment: how to assign the values for sixth column by subtracting existing two columns

Comment: Can you show us your input data? Normally, you can `split` your line and get portion of array. Example: print "Column1;Column2;Column3".split(";")[1]